# Getting a single value from a table dynamically generated by SQL and using it in another table in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I currently have a table generated by a sql query. The url to the page is http://skunkboxstudios.com/dev/ofa-courses/

In the table, there is a button on each row that displays a modal window that shows more details of the row it's on. How do I tell the modal window to only select information regarding the row it's on.

Here is the code for the table on the page:

```
global $wpdb;

$courses = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM section_view;");
$results = array();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Section Name</th>";
echo "<th>Section Description</th>";
echo "<th>Start Date</th>";
echo "<th>End Date</th>";
echo "<th>Location</th>";
echo "<th>Details</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($courses as $course){
    $sectionname = "$course->section_name";
    $sectiondescription = "$course->section_description";
    $sectionstartdate = "$course->term_startdate";
    $sectionenddate = "$course->term_enddate";
    $sectionlocation= "$course->location_name";
    $sectionid = "$course->section_id";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$sectionname</td>";
    echo "<td>$sectiondescription</td>";
    echo "<td>$sectionstartdate</td>";
    echo "<td>$sectionenddate</td>";
    echo "<td>$sectionlocation</td>";
    echo "<td>$sectionid</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<button class='element' onclick='javascript:openDialog();'>Details</button>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The code for the modal window is here:

```
$details = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT * FROM section_view WHERE section_id = '$sectionid';");
foreach($details as $detail){
    echo "<h2>".$detail->section_name."</h2>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$detail->section_name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$detail->section_description."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
echo "<button class='element' onclick='javascript:closeDialog();'>Close</button>";
```

So I need the query in the modal window to SELECT * FROM section_view WHERE section_id = 'the section_id corresponding to the row of the table it's on'

If anybody can help me out, please do. I'll post more information if you need it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a method I use often but I think you need to include the section_id in the URL for your openDialog() call. e.g.

```
echo "<button class='element' onclick='javascript:openDialog(\"myurl.php?sectionid=${sectionid}\");'>Details</button>";
```

You can then include:

```
$sectionid=$_GET["sectionid"];
```

at the top of your modal window script.

Any help?

Comment: I put my url in my openDialog call like you suggested, but it broke it and the modal window wouldn't open anymore. Do I need to put the url in the javascript for the modal window as well? I apologize, I probably should have put that in here as well. Here it is:


    '<script type="text/javascript">
function openDialog() {
Avgrund.show( "#default-popup");
}
function closeDialog() {
Avgrund.hide();
}
</script>'

Answer (score 0):

There are some quick fix as well alternative method of correct process (but obvious a lengthy one)
1. Create a function in functions.php and add your code to modal window there.

1. On click of "details" link call this function using AJAX (make use of admin-ajax.php)
2. return the HTML to display as string from method and show in modal window.

Let me know if further details or assistance is required.